# How to make use of Android Camera API

Tags: android

I want to create an app that takes a picture and then allows to user to play with the picture like maybe give the picture a moustache, its nothing  serious just for fun. I was wondering if anyone could get me started by pointing to some materials.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of using the camera: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

and here's more documentation on the Android Camera API: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

You should read the StackOverflow faq about which questions not to ask... The camera api is the first result when I Googled "Android Camera."

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pages that will get you pointed in the correct direction for using the camera:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Once your user has taken a picture if you display it on a canvas somehow then you can continue to draw to the canvas to add drawings / pictures on the image.